# Adobe Illustrator: How to work with letter shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, pathfinder, corners

I'm having trouble working with letter shapes. I'd like to use the "live corners" feature on a letter "R", but I can't seem to convert the letter into a proper shape... What I've got so far is a compound-path but I can't edit the corners live...

Does anyone have any advice?

P.S.: I'm running Adobe Illustrator CC 2018

[image: Illustration]

Comment: Realize Live Corners is merely a "make that easier" type of feature. No one absolutely *needs* live corners to create the same appearance they do. You can create anything you want without Live Corners, it just may take more work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your letter has to be converted to outlines.

Select and Right click your text box and hit *Convert to outlines*
or 
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

---

You may have to use the *Direct Selection Tool* (<kbd>A</kbd>) <sup><sub>Or holding down <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd></sub></sup>

L: (standard) *Selection Tool* - R: (highlighted) ***Direct*** Selection Tool

[image]

Comment: Thanks for getting back! I've tried what you said but it still doesn't work... I had actually done this before (created outlines) but it didn't work... Any other ideas?

Comment: Even when you switch to Direct Selection?

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work now, on a new document... I don't know what was wrong with my former document but I suspect the file was corrupted or something of the sort? Thanks anyways!!

Answer (score 2):

If you take the Text and outline it. You can then select the text and hold the "CTRL" button to view the like corners. This should help you to do whatever it is you are looking to do with the text.

[image]

When you say it doesn't work tell me how?

I Typed an R
I outlined the text
I held down CTRL
There are live corners

Comment: Thanks for getting back but it's still not working...

Comment: I expanded my answer, but I am unsure of how it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried this on a new document and it worked!! Perhaps my former document file was corrupted? I don't know... Anyways, thanks for your patience and explanation! :)